# Mysql Get count by month and grouped

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying to retrieve results broken into months with quantities. I have it almost working but I need the actual quantity and it is returning the number of entries in the table, not the value. My table and data looks like this:

```
    table products {
     int oid
     datetime date
    } 
    table orders {
     int oid
     int qty
    }

    products
    1, 2018-01-01
    2, 2018-01-01
    3, 2020-01-
    4, 2020-02-01
    }
    orders 
    1, 1,
    2, 4
    3, 2
    4, 3
    }
```

The command I run is

```
    select YEAR(p.date), MONTH(p.date), COUNT(o.qty)
    FROM products p left join orders o using (oid)
    GROUP BY YEAR(p.date), MONTH(p.date)
```

The results I get are

```
    2018 1 2
    2020 1 1
    2020 2 1
```

where they should be

```
    2018 1 5
    2020 1 1
    2020 2 1
```

Would someone please explain how to get the correct quantity by month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `sum()`:

```
SELECT YEAR(p.date), MONTH(p.date), SUM(o.qty)
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     orders o 
     USING (oid)
GROUP BY YEAR(p.date), MONTH(p.date);
```

EDIT:

It looks like you want to handle missing `qty` values as `1`.  Just use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT YEAR(p.date), MONTH(p.date), SUM(COALESCE(o.qty))
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     orders o 
     USING (oid);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9bb51e3dcbeb411d397786a8b313f2ac) is a db<>fiddle.

```
GROUP BY YEAR(p.date), MONTH(p.date)
```

Comment: I just tried sum and it does return the correct quantity but now the dates are not grouped. So I get two results for 2018 instead of one. Is there a way to just have one result per year and month?

Comment: @user3052443 . . . This returns one row per. year and month.  That is how `group by` works.

Comment: So does that mean there isn't a way to return the data in the needed format? I can do it with php but mysql is usually faster for such things.